# Add dropout to Keras Model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, dropout

I would like to add a dropout in hidden layers. I do not know if I should implement the sentence after or before of the definition of each hidden layer.

May somebody help me?

```
def keras_model2(layers_dims):

    L = len(layers_dims)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(layers_dims[1], input_shape=(layers_dims[0],), activation="relu"))

    for l in range(2, L-1):
        model.add(Dense(layers_dims[l], activation="relu", kernel_initializer="random_normal",
                bias_initializer="zeros"))
        model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(layers_dims[L-1], activation="softmax", kernel_initializer="random_normal",
                bias_initializer="zeros"))



    return model
```

Comment: add dropout after the layer you define. Dense -> dropout. This applies if you want the dropout to be applied before the next layer.  https://keras.io/layers/core/

Comment: Ok, in this case I should change the sentence and to move one sentence up to apply all the hidden layers (first one is the entry laye)